# JPA, Can't remove child in onjetomany relationship

Tags: jpa

Now I have three table in database, user, like, and comment, one user can have many likes and comments. In this case,I use JPA to remove record in MYSQL by JAVA EE.
But when I tried to remove specific record in like and comment. Firstly I should find the "likeid" and "commentid", the code shows below.

```
  public  List<Like> findUser(Integer UserId){
            em = factory.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
                User user = em.find(User.class, UserId);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
            List<Like> likes = new ArrayList<Like>();
            likes=user.getLikes();
            return likes;
        }

        public Like findLikebystyleid(String styleid,List<Like> likes)
        {
               for (int i = 0; i < likes.size(); i++) {
                   String temp=likes.get(i).getStyleid();
                   if(temp.equals(styleid))
                   {
                       return likes.get(i);
                       }
             }
            return null;
        }
```

And then I find "likeid"

```
public Integer Getremoveid(Integer userid,String styleid)
{
    List<Like> likes = new ArrayList<Like>();
    Like like=new Like();
    likes=findUser(userid);
    like=findLikebystyleid(styleid,likes);
    try {return like.getId();
    }
    catch(Exception E){}
    return -1;
}
```

Finally I remove the record in database by em.

```
    public List<Like> removelike (Integer id)
{
    List<Like> likes = new ArrayList<Like>();
    em = factory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Like like=new Like();
    try{
    like=em.find(Like.class, id);
    em.remove(like);

    Query query = em.createQuery("select like from Like like");
    likes = query.getResultList();

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    return likes;
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    return null;


}
```

But the record still exist in database. I don't know why since nearly the same code I implement in comment, the record can be removed.
the comment code showed below:

```
public  List<Comment> findCommentsbyUser(Integer UserId){
    em = factory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
        User user = em.find(User.class, UserId);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
    comments=user.getComments();
    return comments;

}
public Comment findbystyleid(String styleid,List<Comment> comments)
{
       for (int i = 0; i < comments.size(); i++) {
           String temp=comments.get(i).getStyleid();
           if(temp.equals(styleid))
           {                   
               return comments.get(i);
               }
     }
    return null;
}




public Integer Getremoveid(Integer userid,String styleid)
    {
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
        Comment comment=new Comment();
        comments=findCommentsbyUser(userid);
        comment=findbystyleid(styleid,comments);
        try {Integer id=comment.getId();
        return id;
        }
        catch(Exception E){}
        return -1;
    }   
public List<Comment> removecomment (Integer id)
    {
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

        em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Comment comment=new Comment();
        try{
        comment = em.find(Comment.class, id);
        em.remove(comment);
        Query query = em.createQuery("select comment from Comment comment");
        comments = query.getResultList();

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        return comments;
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        return null;
    }
```

I don't know why this happening ,this drive me crazy. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to commit first in order that the change is really reflected in the database ... In case of Comments, you committed `em.getTransaction().commit();` , which is not the case for Likes